# How can I realize operator $\frac{D}{e^D-1}$ in Mathematica?

Tags: operators

Especially if it is applied to an integral of a function.

So, I need for a given function `f[t]` the following:

$\frac{D}{e^D-1} \int_0^t f(t)dt |_{t=\omega}$

Comment: @Bob Hanlon definitely, it is far from what I need, I need this operator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Representation_by_a_differential_operator ; http://mathoverflow.net/questions/266046/transformation-converting-power-series-to-bernoulli-polynomial-series

Comment: Recommend that you edit your post to include that link.